# Query Entire Junction Table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Hi there I am using Linq to Entities and I have a junction table (many to many) userroles between users and roles since it is a junction table it is not available in the Ado.net entity model.

Is there a way to query this table using Linq to entities.
(I need to retrieve all data in my table userroles)

Thanks

Comment: What do you need to do with this data? Would it be enough to *pretend* you have the table by reading all the information out of the Users and Roles tables?

Comment: Check [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097992/linq-to-entities-many-to-many-select-query) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082001/linq-to-entities-many-to-many-select).

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ExecuteSqlCommand** method for such queries.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Your SQL Script");
```